# How do I upload/download with Googledrive package using R?

Tags: r

I can upload a file using R to google drive.
I can then find the file using r code.
I CANNOT then download the same file using R.

I've looked through all the resources on the web, including stackoverflow, with no joy.

```
drive_upload("/Users/me/Desktop/abcxx.xlsx", type = "spreadsheet")
drive_find(pattern="abcxx", n_max=30)
drive_download("abcxx", type="spreadsheet")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in add_id_path(nodes, root_id = root_id, leaf = leaf) : 
  !anyDuplicated(nodes$id) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drive_download() is finding multiple items that match the pattern. If you run

```
drive_find(pattern = "abcxx")
```

without the n_max, you will likely see that it is finding many items (even if running it with the n_max only returns one item). I'm not sure why this is.

In any case, the solution to your problem is identifying the file by its id rather than the pattern using as_id(). If

```
drive_find(pattern = "abcxx", n_max=30)
```

is only returning one item, you could simply run

```
drive_download(as_id(drive_find(pattern="abcxx", n_max=30)$id)))
```

This isn't part of your question but you probably also want to specify the path and filename of the file you want to create, e.g.

```
drive_download(
file = as_id(drive_find(pattern="abcxx", n_max=30)$id)),
path = "~/Downloads"
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does.  There is a slight error, I believe in your code.  The "
type = "spreadsheet")" does not work, but if you delete that code fragment it works fine.  And your second answer regarding the Path was indeed very helpful too.  By chance, how do I upload to a specific folder in google drive?

Answer (score 2):

Replying to:
*Yes, it does. There is a slight error, I believe in your code. The " type = "spreadsheet")" does not work, but if you delete that code fragment it works fine. And your second answer regarding the Path was indeed very helpful too. By chance, how do I upload to a specific folder in google drive?*

This should work:

Get the id for the folder you're trying to upload to using `drive_get()`

Then you can set the path argument in `drive_upload()` to that id using the argument `path=as_id(p)`

An example of uploading a csv to drive as a google sheet:

```
p<- drive_get('path/to/folder/')

drive_upload('localfile.csv',path=as_id(p),type = 'spreadsheet',name ='local file')
```

Comment: The folder I have on google drive is "Timesheets". The command I am using, per your advice is p<- drive_get('Timesheets/').  It does not work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give an example of the error you're getting?  I'm assuming 'Timesheets' is a folder in the home directory ( technically folders are just metadata info)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write some code that would go to a specific folder on google drive and download all of the files in the folder.  I was not able to get the recommended code example above to work, but this code does work:

```
week <- "w39"
download_path <- "/Users/user/Desktop/Gdrive/"

f <- drive_ls(path = as_id(drive_find(pattern = week, n_max = 30)$id))

for (i in 1:nrow(f)){

  d_path <- f$name[i]

  drive_download(file = as_id(drive_find(pattern = f$name[i], n_max = 30)$id), 
                 path = paste(download_path, d_path, sep =""),
                 overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dnield has the correct answer, but my problem is that `drive_find()` takes a LONG LONG time (maybe I have too many files on Google Drive?). So instead I just manually deleted the duplicate file name. That fixed the problem.