# In R, importing '.jpeg' from public shared GDrive link

Tags: r, google-image-search, google-drive-shared-drive

How to import image in GDrive public folder/file in R?

Tried few other stuff listed on various platforms, didn't work.

Also, this is a bit tricky because the loading is not instantaneous.

Eg link: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsXN8QlUZVV6dtZaBjDWSpb44TjMNdJJ/edit"

Edit:
With ideas/links from Rui Barradas (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas), the following worked:
drive_download("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsXN8QlUZVV6dtZaBjDWSpb44TjMNdJJ/edit")

Comment: Does [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794378/8245406) answer your question?

Comment: @RuiBarradas - helps, not directly, but got an idea and solved it. Mentioned in edits. Thanks